# ¿Cómo obtener una variable de HTML a partir de un script a PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

De este código HTML ¿cómo extraigo la variable **winningSegment.text** para convertirla en **$variable** de php?

Enjemplo: **$variable = winningSegment.text;**

Misma pregunta mismo objetivo hecha de diferente manera

Osea ¿como saco esa **winningSegment.text** variable de la etiqueta para poder usarla en una variable de php?

Enjemplo: **$variable = winningSegment.text;**

He logrado hacer que envie pero SIN ERROR al cambiar la linea (**"premi" : winningSegment.text** por **'premi' : "MiPremio"**) ¿como le hago para que me funcione con **"premi" : winningSegment.text**? en vez de **'premi' : "MiPremio"**

***IMPOTANTE*** Todo esta en un solo archivo mi archivo.JS

```
        var objRuleta;
         var winningSegment;
         var distnaciaX = 150;
         var distnaciaY = 60;
         var ctx ;
         function Mensaje() {
             winningSegment = objRuleta.getIndicatedSegment();
             SonidoFinal();
             swal({
                 title: "Has ganado: " + winningSegment.text,
                 // imageUrl: "img/Muerte.png",
                 // showCancelButton: true,
                 confirmButtonColor: "#e74c3c",
                 confirmButtonText: "Ok,Reiniciar"
                 // cancelButtonText: "Quitar elemento",
                 // closeOnConfirm: true,
                 // closeOnCancel: true
             },
      function (isConfirm) {
          if (isConfirm) {
             
          } else {

              $('#ListaElementos').val($('#ListaElementos').val().replace(winningSegment.text,""));
              leerElementos();
              
          }
          objRuleta.stopAnimation(false);
          objRuleta.rotationAngle = 0;
          objRuleta.draw();
          DibujarTriangulo();
          bigButton.disabled = false;
      });

      }

         function DibujarTriangulo() {
             distnaciaX = 150;
             distnaciaY = 2;
             ctx = objRuleta.ctx;
             ctx.strokeStyle = 'navy';
             ctx.fillStyle = '#HGFGGH';
             ctx.lineWidth = 2;
             ctx.beginPath();
             ctx.moveTo(distnaciaX + 170, distnaciaY + 5);
             ctx.lineTo(distnaciaX + 230, distnaciaY + 5);
             ctx.lineTo(distnaciaX + 200, distnaciaY + 40);
             ctx.lineTo(distnaciaX + 171, distnaciaY + 5);
             ctx.stroke();
             ctx.fill();
         }

         function DibujarRuleta(ArregloElementos) {
             
               objRuleta = new Winwheel({
                 'canvasId': 'Ruleta',
                 'numSegments': ArregloElementos.length,
                 'outerRadius': 340,
                 'innerRadius': 1,
                 'segments':ArregloElementos,
                 'animation':
                 {
                     'type': 'spinToStop',
                     'duration':2,
                     'spins': 15,
                     'callbackFinished': 'Mensaje()',
                     'callbackAfter': 'DibujarTriangulo()' 
                     
                 }, 
                
             });
    
               DibujarTriangulo();
      }
        function leerElementos() {
                  txtListaElementos=$('#ListaElementos').val().trim();
                  var Elementos = txtListaElementos.split('\n');
                  var ElementosRuleta= [];
              Elementos.forEach(function (Elemento) {
                      if(Elemento){
                      ElementosRuleta.push({ 'fillStyle': "#" + ((1 << 24) * Math.random() | 0).toString(16), 'text': Elemento });
                  }
                  });
                  DibujarRuleta(ElementosRuleta);
         } 
         leerElementos();
          var audio = new Audio('alarma.mp3');  // Create audio object and load desired file.
        function SonidoFinal()
            {
                audio.pause();
                audio.currentTime = 0;
                audio.play();
            }
//bloque inicia ajax
function insertar_premio(){
    var envias = document.getElementById('bigButton').value;
    // var entera = winningSegment.text;
    var parametrs = {
        'premi' : "MiPremio"
    };
    $.ajax({
        data: parametrs,
        url: './insert.php',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response){
            $('#datos').html(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Aqui quiero ponerlo asi

```
function insertar_premio(){
    var envias = document.getElementById('bigButton').value;
    // var entera = winningSegment.text;
    var parametrs = {
        'premi' : winningSegment.text
    };
    $.ajax({
        data: parametrs,
        url: './insert.php',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response){
            $('#datos').html(response);
        }
    });
}
```

El problema es que al ponerlo lo que es la ruleta se desactiva la opcion de girar por lo tanto el script mismo deja de funcionar y se inabilita.

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Qué quiere decir exactamente *sacar el valor de la variable* y dónde quieres sacarlo?

Comment: La ultima vez que me extendi nadie respondio por que alguien dijo "NO DEBEMOS LEER TODO EL CODIGO" ahora te explico segun esta ruleta que es una ruleta de premios https://github.com/jvczxc/rullete observa el area text  dice Premio 2 bueno es se refleja en la ruleta para ver el proyecto descargalo creo no estoy seguro saco el premio ¿de aqui? confirmButtonText: 'Ok,Reiniciar',

Comment: El problem es que JavaScript corre en el navigador y PHP corre en el sirvador.  La única manera de pasar valores de JavaScript o HTML a PHP es por POST o GET.

Comment: y como haria eso hermano?

Comment: Ahora envíe un ejemplo de como hacerlo

Comment: El php donde recibes el json debe ser otro archivo

Comment: Sí o sí, debes hacerlo utilizando Ajax. Si no consigues una respuesta te publicaré una con la explicación incluida.

Comment: Amigo el pana va por buen camino pero no estaria de mas una ayuda gracias es que debo pasar esa variable a php y no dejarla en html no es lo que quiero ya que su uso final es buscar ejecutar una consulta a base de datos y esa consulta es la variable que deseo extraer.

Comment: @Benjamin Alexis Rivas Beltran brother, consegui ya que envie consultas por ajax a mi base de datos pero no envia el resultado de la tabla no se cual es el error.

Comment: ahora vi que en la función ajax me equivoqué en unas letras que eran mayúsculas xDD ahora lo corrijo

Comment: Listo eran unos errores de letras copia de nueva la función ajax

Comment: Bro encontre algo mas facil pero no consigo el error creo que editare mi pregunta por que la verdad ve uy complicado tu script y este me funciona pero con texto agregado mira. egragare mi respuesta mas abajo.

Comment: Hermano replantee la pregunta tras tu amable ayuda, replantee la pregunta y incluso la acorte pues el problema creo se simplifica a enviar una variable a ajax deja de funcionar el script no se si lo que me mensionas me ayuda. pues mira mi edicion

Answer (score 1):

No lo puedes hacerlo directamente en un solo archivo, pero puedes usar AJAX, te mostrare como:

En tu html, **al comienzo del script**, defines la siguiente función:

```javascript
// Creamos la función ajax, la cual recibirá como parámetros el objeto a enviar (data), la url del archivo PHP (url) y la función que recibirá los datos (callback)
function ajax(data, url, callback) {
    // creamos un XMLHttpRequest
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // creamos la función onreadystatechange de la xhr, la cual se ejecutará cuando avancé la petición
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status) {
            // ejecutamos la función, pasándole como parámetro el texto de respuesta
            callback(xhr.responseText)
        }
    }
    // Creamos un json con el objeto que queremos enviar
    const json = JSON.stringify(data)
    // Establecemos el método con el que queremos hacer la petición, la url y, como es asíncrona, el tercer parámetro será true
    xhr.open("POST", url, true)
    // Ponemos las cabeceras de la petición como si fuera un formulario, necesario si se utiliza POST
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    // Enviamos la petición con el json del objeto
    xhr.send(`json=${json}`)
}
```

creas un nuevo archivo `miArchivo.php` **Este debe ser un otro archivo**:

```php
<?php
// defines una variable variable con la información del json
$data = json_decode($_POST["json")
// aquí puedes usar la info del json
?>
```

y cuando quieras enviar el objeto usas esto:

```js
ajax(winningSegment, "miArchivo.php", (data) => {
    // aquí se usa cualquier dato que imprimas en miArchivo.php
})
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123857/discussion-on-answer-by-benjamin-alexis-rivas-beltran-como-obtener-una-variable).

Comment: Y quien esta discutiendo bro? Yo no y creo que el amigo @Benjamin Alexis Rivas Beltran tampoco mas bien ha sido bien colavorador y buena onda. estamos es buscando una solucion amigo

Comment: Un chat y donde cuelgo el script yo no estoy discutiendo estoy pidiendo ayuda para un cangrejo xDDD no estoy peleando ni nada de hecho cambie el script y ya me ejecuta pero no envia la variable

Comment: tengo dudas bro en tu respuesta yo tengo que editar o copiar y pegar? es que no veo de donde recoje los datos el primer script

Comment: yo edité la función ajax, copia y pega

Comment: el resultado se usa en la función de tercer código, si haces console.log(data) te imprimirá por consola el resultado del script php

Comment: Bro lee chat para que edites la respuesta https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123857/discussion-on-answer-by-benjamin-alexis-rivas-beltran-como-obtener-una-variable ya consegui como solucionar mas facil o respondo yo?